# NameError: name 'clean_text' is not defined

Tags: nlp, data-science, countvectorizer

I am learning on how to implement nlp, so i started with data cleaning and now i am trying to Vectorizing Data using bag-of-words, this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import re
import nltk
stopword=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
wn=nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


count_vect=CountVectorizer(analyzer=clean_text)
x_count=count_vect.fit_transform(lematizing_words)
print(x_count.shape)
```

but, when i run this code i get the following error

> NameError: name 'clean_text' is not defined

how can i solve this?

i have referred [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-nlp-for-machine-learning-d44498845d5b) blog for the nlp implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def cleanText(text):
    text = "".join([word.lower() for word in text if word not in string.punctuation])
    tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
    text = [ps.stem(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
    return text

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```

Here is the function that the Badreesh put into github but is not in the blog.

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes well your problem. What is `clean_text` ? Have you defined a `clean_text` function? Or imported the right python module containing this function?

Comment: i dont have any idea about it, the blog which i am following has this line "count_vect=CountVectorizer(analyzer=clean_text)" which is used to predict the using NLP. blog link(https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-nlp-for-machine-learning-d44498845d5b)